# devise: undefined method `user=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise, rubygems

I'm trying to implement the devise gem into my web app - everything with user login and registration is working, but when a user tries to actually leave a prediction (the only thing you need to be logged in for), I get this error message: undefined method `user=' for nil:NilClass. I can't seem to figure out what's causing this problem. Might anyone know?

_login_items.html.erb:

```
<ul>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

prediction model:

```
class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :predictions
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

predictions migration:

```
class CreatePredictions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :predictions do |t|
      t.string :prediction
      t.belongs_to :student, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

user migration:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
  t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
       # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

predictions controller:

```
class PredictionsController <ApplicationController
def create
    @prediction.user = current_user
    Prediction.create(prediction_params)
    redirect_to :back
end

def new
    @prediction = Prediction.new(student_id: params[:student_id])
end

def destroy
    Prediction.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :back
end

private
def prediction_params
    params.require(:prediction).permit(:prediction) #, :student_id
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your PredictionsController. You have to create the prediction and assign it to a variable first. Change your create action to this:

```
def create
    @prediction = Prediction.create(prediction_params)
    @prediction.user = current_user
    redirect_to :back
end
```

You were trying to assign a user to a non existing prediction. This correction creates the prediction first then assigns the user to it.

Edit: I noticed one other problem: Your `prediction_params` method is incorrect. The arguments you pass to the `permit` method must be the attributes of your prediction model which you want to mass assign. The `:prediction` key in the params is the one you want to require but within that nested hash you want to permit attributes of the `prediction` model. So, hypothetically, if your prediction model has `:name`, `:value` and `:student_id`  attributes, your `prediction_params` method should look like this:

```
def prediction_params
    params.require(:prediction).permit(:name, :value, :student_id)
end
```

This will work with a `params` hash that looks like:

```
{
  prediction: {
    name: 'something',
    value: 'stuff',
    student_id: 1
  }
}
```